# Getting different PIDs from unshare

Tags: bash, unshare

Here's some of the basic code inside a script called `test.sh`.

```bsh
bash -c "sleep 10; echo \$(pidof unshare)" &

sudo unshare --mount --uts --ipc --net --pid --fork /bin/sh -c "
... do stuff ...
sleep 60
" &

PID=$!
```

When I execute the script, the process IDs identified by the background bash command on the first line and the value assigned to PID are different. Additionally, if you run a `ps` in the script, I don't see either of those process IDs. I'm guessing that I'm passing the code to unshare incorrectly to make it all run as a single process in the background? How can I get the actual PID of the process running in the background in the new namespace?

Comment: Are you aware the double-quoted `$(pidof unshare)` is evaluated (by the shell interpreting `test.sh`) before `bash -c` runs? I guess this is not what you wanted. In general `echo $(stuff)` is [hardly ever useful](https://superuser.com/q/1352850/432690).

Comment: Yea, that was a typo on my part, in the script the `$` is escaped, updated post with the change.